# Hyper-V: Create virtual network, with LAN access, but without Internet access

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, lan, hyper-v, windows-10-preview

I'm pretty paranoid when it comes to Windows 10's "data collecting". But I need to set up a Windows 10 VM on my build machine for development purposes.
I basically want to be able to send files to that Windows 10 VM through my LAN, but the Windows 10 machine cannot have Internet access (which is problematic because my LAN provides Internet access).

So my question is: How can I create a virtual network switch with Hyper-V, that does just this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't specify a wireless adapter, and you are set! It's in the settings.

Right-click the Virtual Computer in `Hyper-V Manager`, click `Settings>Network Adapter>Virtual Switch`, and set to `Not Connected`.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. You can, however, set a static IP configuration inside the VM, leaving out DNS servers and the gateway. That will make it unable to communicate with anything outside your local network.

Comment: If you just leave the DNS wouldn't that only block DNS resolving? Are you certain, that Windows does not use a special method to report your data to their servers? I'm also wondering if it wouldn't be possible, that Windows would try to send the data during startup ignoring the IP config at first.

Comment: That right, it would just prevent regular name resolution. That’s why I also said not to set a default gateway. Certainly this could be bypassed, but if you’re that paranoid, you just can’t put it on the/any network.

Answer (score 0):

According to my Windows Server class on TestOut LabSim, there are three types of virtual networks you can set up in Hyper-V. You might want an Internal network (you could put a file on the host hypervisor and then move it to the vm). Or, you could use a router to block access to the internet from the VM's mac or IP address.

- External.    In an external network, VMs bind to the physical NIC, which
  allows them to access the physical network. Use this option to allow
  the VM to communicate with the host operating system, other VMs
  running on the system, and other physical network devices.
- Internal.
  In an internal network, VMs can communicate with one another and
  with the host operating system, but cannot access the physical
  network. This configuration is typically used to build a test network
  where you connect to the VMs through the management operating system.
- Private.  In a private network, VMs can communicate with each
  other but cannot communicate with the host operating system or access
  the physical network. This network type is optimal when a VM needs to
  have a degree of isolation.